# Django: Why i m getting 404 when i try to delete an object from my database?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i have an uploads model and i want to be able to delete the images, so i wrote a delete request that takes the id of the image however i keep getting 404 not found, i have the same thing and same steps for the files model that i created and it works fine.

```js
@api_view(['GET', 'POST','DELETE'])
def Upload_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        queryset = Uploads.objects.all()
        uploads=queryset.filter(owner=request.user)
        serializer = UploadSerializer(uploads, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = UploadSerializer(data=request.data)
      
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(owner=request.user)
            respFile=list(File.objects.filter(id=str(File.objects.latest('created_at'))))
            serializers=Fileserializers(respFile,read_only=True,many=True)
            return Response(serializers.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

def UploadsDetails(request,pk):
    try:
        image=Uploads.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Uploads.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(status=404)
    if request.method =='GET':
        serializers=Fileserializers(image)
        return JsonResponse(serializers)
    elif request.method =='DELETE':
        image.delete()
        return HttpResponse(status=204)
```

these are the urls:

```js
from django.urls import path
from .views import  Upload_list,login
from .views import UploadsDetails


urlpatterns=[
    path('Uploads/',Upload_list),
    path('Uploads/<uuid:pk>/',UploadsDetails),
    path('login/', login)
]
```

[image]

Comment: Change the request method in postman to delete instead of get

Comment: i tried both, same result for get and delete

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add `decorator` to your `function`

```
@api_view(['GET','DELETE'])
def UploadsDetails(request,pk):
       pass
```

Comment: i tried that but it didn't change anything

Comment: The same error? maybe you entered an `id`  that doesn't exist in your `database`

Comment: i forgot to add  path('Uploads/<uuid:pk>/',UploadsDetails),  to the projects urls, i got it fixed, thanks